# Pass variable value to form field

Tags: python, django

How can I pass the value of a variable to the value attribute of a field in my form? I have tried overriding the **init** method but I can't get it to work. This is my code.

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserManegement, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.TextField(user, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.TextField(user, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.TextField(user, null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar', 'first_name','last_name', 'phone']
        widgets = {
            'avatar': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control-file mt-3'}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mt-3', 'placeholder': 'Nombre'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mt-3', 'placeholder': 'Apellidos'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mt-3', 'placeholder':'Teléfono'}),
        }
```

views.py:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')
    template_name = 'registration/profile_form.html'

    def get_object(self):
        #recuperamos el objeto para editarlo
        profile, created =  Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        
        return profile
```

In this case, I would like to add the first time the form is loaded, the first_name field with the value of request.user.first_name.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Share the view where you use the form...

Answer (score 2):

You can override the [**`.get_initial(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) to provide intial values for a form, but since here you pass an instance to the form, it will take the values of the instance. You thus can create a `Profile` with the username:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ProfileUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')
    template_name = 'registration/profile_form.html'

    def get_object(self):
        #recuperamos el objeto para editarlo
        return Profile.objects.get_or_create(
            user=self.request.user,
            defaults={'first_name': self.request.user.first_name}
        )[0]
```

I'm however not sure that creating an instance in the `UpdateView` is a good idea. A GET request is supposed to have no side effects, but here you create a `Profile` when you make a GET request to the page.

Furthermore you also duplicate data, since now both the `User` and the `Profile` carry a `first_name` attribute. It is thus possible that the `first_name` of the `User` and its related `Profile` is different, resulting in all sorts of inconsistencies.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: I have tried what you have posted. Then in form.py, inside the field I want the value to appear, I have to put this:
'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mt-3', 'placeholder': 'Name'}, initial='first_name'), where what I'm including is initial?

Comment: @vien2: but it will not use the `initial`, since this is an `UpdateView`, it will pass the *instance* passed to the form, and use *that* value. `initial` is only given you create a *new* instance in the form.

Comment: I have entered that line, but it does not change anything.  The first_name of the user still does not appear the first time the view is loaded. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @vien2: because you already created a `Profile` for that user *before* you changed the line?

Comment: That was it, I had a bug in the code. Thank you very much for your help!